# My website is responsive when I resize the browser on desktop, but when I go on an actual mobile device, it isn't responsive

Tags: html, css, web, responsive

I want my website to be responsive on all platforms (especially mobile), not just on a desktop when resizing the browser window.

I have used the meta viewport tags in my `<head>` that other similar threads say I should do, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 2):

What's not working with the viewport tag @Rohan? I noticed that it was missing from your template

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with the viewport tag. It seems like mobile phones completely ignore it. I do have that ^ tag in my head. Why do you say it is missing?

Comment: Really? Weird, when I inspect your page this is all the head tag contains

Comment: `<head>
  <title>Rohan Taneja</title>  
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
</head>`

Comment: <head>
 <!-- meta -->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

This is what I have in my code ^

Comment: Oh ya. When I inspect my website myself I see that too. Why is the browser not showing it? It is in the index.html file I uploaded to the hosting service.

Comment: I think that might be the problem buddy, try to get that resolved and loop back. Maybe you pushed a branch from git that didn't have those changes? Otherwise try a Google search of "YOUR HOSTING COMPANY not recognizing meta data", or ping the Help department

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I am using Google Cloud Storage to host my website for free and I have not used GitHub at all. 

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website
^ this is how I hosted my site.

Comment: Fixed it! I just paid for hosting from an actual hosting company instead of trying to use a free workaround. I guess there are benefits to buying actual legit hosting...

Comment: Nice dude, looks great on my iPhone